# Javascript - Changing img tag src using Javascript doesn't reflect sometimes

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have created a custom control using Javascript where you swipe between icons and any time an icon is in the middle of the screen it gets replaced with a different image, the problem is sometimes the new image doesn't update, when I inspect the source I can see that my img tag has the new image set like in this screenshot:

[image]

(Note that the icon in the page is blue while it should be green as per the src)

After this point if I try to change the src of any image in the page using the console it won't work, the page Javascript still works fine but I can no longer change any image src.

This is the Javascript I use to update the image, note that I update the image class before I update the src.

```
// update selected item class
document.getElementById("scroll-item-" + selectItemId).className = "scroll-item-selected";

// update selected item image
var currentItemImageElement = document.getElementById("scroll-image-" + $scope.currentSelectItemId);
currentItemImageElement.src = currentItemImageElement.src.substring(0, currentItemImageElement.src.length - 11) + ".png";
// update selected image class
currentItemImageElement.className = "icon-img";
```

Comment: Show us what JS code you tried.

Comment: I've edited the post with the JS code

Comment: you put there really small piece of code, eg. where is defined `selectItemId` variable? How you call this change in your HTML? If it's only change image for image (eg. blue in a normal state and green during hover state), better way than changing `src` attribute is to change background in CSS using CSS sprites.

Comment: Each image is in its own div and all those divs are in a container div that has a scroll, on the container div scroll event I calculate the position and replace the class of the image in the middle and its div and then I update the image src.

My divs are named scroll-item-0 -> scroll-item-4, the selectItemId is the index.

Answer (score 0):

I would try preloading your images, either as:

- a sprite, since you are adding classes
- `img` tags in the DOM with `display: none` as a poor man's preloader

Then see if you still have issues. My initial thoughts are that your images have not been loaded and see you are seeing an artifact of that.

Comment: I'll try preloading my images and report back. The puzzling part is that it works 90% of the time correctly.